# jQuery + IE8 Ajax Json parse error

Tags: php, jquery

I have a script that calls the server via $.ajax() with jQuery and it works well on Chrome or FF but not in IE 8.

This my call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'location.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data){
      alert('Ajax made!');
      $.each(data, function(key, val) {

         var lat = null;
         var lng = null;
         var title = null;
         var id = null;

         $.each(val, function(index, vol) {

            if(index == 'id')
                id = vol;
            else if(index == 'lng')
                lng = vol;
            else if(index == 'lat')
                lat = vol;
            else if(index == 'nombre')
                title = vol;    
         });

                     // Create marker in the Google Map
         createMaker(id,lat,lng,title);
      });       
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            // I get Error on IE 8
    alert(jqXHR.responseText);
  }
});
```

This the code on the server side:

```
    header( 'Content-type: application/json' );

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die('Existe un problema al  conectar a la base de datos. Disculpe las molestias');
mysql_select_db($dbname);
    mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
    $result = mysql_query("select id,lat,lng,nombre from location");


$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}


print json_encode($rows);

// close the connection
mysql_close($conn);
```

The result json is something like this:

<!---->
[{"id":"3","lat":"19.700800","lng":"-101.186972","nombre":"Victor Manuel Mendoza Armas"}]

Dont know why my php add the <!----> on the top of the response.

Maybe is this the problem?

Comment: Any include files that might be outputting those HTML comments?

Comment: Yes was that the problem, i included one PHP and it has a html comment. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with google app engine but with python.
[In Google app engine dev server, simplejson.dumps is sending data that contains header info that reads True,0,1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123481/solved-in-google-app-engine-dev-server-simplejson-dumps-is-sending-data-that-c)

It appears that if you have some random print statements, this is caused. Maybe same with PHP.

Comment: On that PHP script i only have one print the json_encode($rows) nothing else. Dont know why the PHP is sending that at the begining of the response.